# Jekyll: Run a custom piece of code whenever a new page is built?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm trying to learn my way around Jekyll, and I have my simple blog up and running. Now, I'd like to run a piece of external Ruby code whenever a new blog post is created.

For example, I currently have Jekyll running with the `--watch` mode. When I save a new blog post file, it gets automatically built. When this happens, I'd like to run a piece of Ruby code, preferrably with information about the new post (such as the post title and a link to the post).

I read through the [documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/) about plug-ins, and I assume this could be done with a plug-in. However, that's all I've found out. So: how would one write such a plug-in? Or, if there is a simpler way, how would one call a custom piece of Ruby code with information about a new blog post?

Answer (score -1):

Did you considered to do the opposite? What about to create a rails application using Redcarpet?

https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet

You can also watch this railscasts (although is from 2011): http://railscasts.com/episodes/272-markdown-with-redcarpet